# Python - 'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this `dictionary`:

```
 playlists = {
    u'user1': {u'Make You Feel My Love': 1.0, u'I See Fire': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'One': 1.0, u'Goodbye My Lover': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0}, 
    u'user2': {u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0}, 
    u'user3': {u'Codex': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Go It Alone': 1.0}, 
    u'user4': {u'No Distance Left To Run': 1.0, u'Running Up That Hill': 1.0, u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'The Numbers': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0}, u'user5': {u'Wild Wood': 1.0, u'You Do Something To Me': 1.0, u'Reprise': 1.0}}
```

and I'm trying to fetch `float values`.

with:

```
print playlist.keys()[0]
print [p for p in playlist.values()[0]]
```

I succeed.

but if I try `[p.values() for p in playlist.values()]`, I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'`

how do I get `values`?

Comment: It's `playlists` not `playlist` and it works fine for me.

Comment: `[p for p in playlist.values()[0].values()]` to get values within the values => returns the floats.

Comment: If it gives that error, then `playlist` must be a different variable.  It works with that dictionary, but only if the variable name for the dictionary and the variable name in the list comprehension are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your `dict` as "playlists" (plural) but in your later code snippets you work on a variable named "playlist" (singular). FWIW, using the original `playlists` definition, your list comp works (or course) perfectly:

```
>>> playlists = {
...     u'user1': {u'Make You Feel My Love': 1.0, u'I See Fire': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'One': 1.0, u'Goodbye My Lover': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0}, 
...     u'user2': {u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0}, 
...     u'user3': {u'Codex': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Go It Alone': 1.0}, 
...     u'user4': {u'No Distance Left To Run': 1.0, u'Running Up That Hill': 1.0, u'Fake Plastic Trees': 1.0, u'The Numbers': 1.0, u'No Surprises': 1.0}, u'user5': {u'Wild Wood': 1.0, u'You Do Something To Me': 1.0, u'Reprise': 1.0}}
>>> [p.values() for p in playlists.values()]
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
```

IOW, please learn what's "minimal complete and **verifiable**" example mean...